# Whom or Who in this sentence: These men, all of WHOM or WHO were well-known, well-respected statesmen, were viewed by their peers

Tags: grammar, american-english, whom

Here's the full sentence: "These men, all of who were well-known, well-respected statesmen, were viewed by their peers and common people alike as great thinkers in their day.

I just can't really see where it would fall into: subject? predicate? object? What would it be?

Comment: It's the object of the preposition *of*. *All* is the subject.

Comment: @tchrist No, it's not a dupe. This sentence actually requires *whom* because it's the object of a preposition. An issue that is ignored in the answers to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the formula I use for on-the-fly decisions on this common dilemma"

**Who = he (singular) / they (plural)

Whom = him (singular) / them (plural)**

Substitute the translations in the appropriate phrase:

*...all of they were well-known... (?)

...all of them were well-known... (?)*

Of course the proper choice is "them." So

***...all of whom were well-known...***

Comment: So I definitely upvoted that answer, and so long as that works 100% of the time, I may start a new religion around you. lol. So, are there circumstances in which that does not always work?

Comment: Not that I have stumbled across. The only issue that troubles some is identifying the phrase to which the formula should apply. For example, in, "To who/whom should I address my reply?" some might struggle with the concept of re-working the phrase to find the solution. In this example, one must mentally answer the question to find the solution: "I should address my reply to he/him." Solution becomes obvious: him = whom.

Comment: @JimmyG. This s one of the only times that it matters. When *who/m* isn't the object of a preposition, you can use *who* in nearly all instances.